# Rdlc with two "synchronized tables"

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I'm using rdlc files to generate pdf files.

What I basically want to do to is to display the data of my data set on two "synchronized" tables.

The image below represents the result I would like to obtain:

[image]

The image represents one page of the pdf, on which the data is group by a certain attribute of the dataset.

Please tell me if any clarification is needed, it's hard for me to explain clearly.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Trouble splitting the data in 2 sets or?

Comment: I don't know how to create two synchronised groups, should I use two tables inside a list?

Comment: If you add them as seperate tables on the pdf then you would need to filter and select the right columns to show from the main dataset. You could do this with `LINQ` on the moment you make up te tables.

Comment: I think it should be enough to use two Tablix and assign them the same dataset.

Comment: @CynicalSection If I do this, would'nt the two tablix display one after the other, I mean I would get pages with only the first tablix then pages with only the second tablix?

Comment: @Platus, do you want to have 2 tables as a single object? That can also generate rows on a new page. It depends on the dataset record count

Comment: How can i do that with 2 tables as a single object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i do that with 2 tables as a single object?

I managed to do this with a Tablix as the container. Add two lines of header and add another two Tablix to each cell of header with data. You cannot use Data row, you have to remove it. You can add a Tablix to a cell with drag and drop. 
In the end, you will have something like : [image]

Probably something alike can be achieved with subreports, but I'm not familiar with them.

EDIT: 
Added screenshot

I believe this is what you want to see. 1 column, 3 rows Tablix. In Cells(1,1) and (3,1) you have other Tablix objects that you can customize.
[image]

Comment: Could you please give a screenshot of your rdlc showing each element, thanks